# Efficiency in creating a tab CSS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want to ask what is more efficient when creating a group of tabs, made in css3 or a jquery? Example you want to create a tabs that compose of different content: for the tab1 a content something like tables, for tab2 a content something like graphs.

Comment: CSS is native. jQuery is a framework. As a general rule, that means CSS will be more efficient. Now, as for being easy to work with... jQuery wins that one (since that's kind of the point of frameworks)

Comment: If browser compatibility is not an issue then go with CSS because sometimes jquery tabs becomes jerky which you wont like it . it also doesn't seems to be working properly in mobile devices otherwise for compatibility use jquery !

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol would there be any problem if I use css? I just kind of wanting to use css rather than jquery.

Comment: @surajrawat that is one of the problem with jquery tabs

Comment: No there is no harm to use css if your targeted browser supports css3 otherwise use jquery

Comment: @surajrawat thanks! I think I'm just going to use jquery, I don't want to have a problem with the compatibility.

Comment: Yes you should go ahead @robertpeter07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that I can use, [SimpleTabs](http://fotis.co/projects/simpletabs/)

1. It does not depend on any third-part library like jQuery, Mootools etc. That means it won't conflict with scripts made with these libraries or any other script.
2. It does not need different IDs per tab container in order to have multiple tab sets. So, you can have as many SimpleTabs tab sets as you want on the same page.
3. It remembers the last tab clicked on and if you reload the page (e.g. navigate somewhere and return to the page containing the tabs) that specific tab is already active.
4. It's simple to implement, small in size and fast to load.
   Works on all browsers.